# Apply disableRemoteMethod for a lot of models

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

How I can apply this to all my models?

common/models/task.js

```
module.exports = function(Task) {

  Task.disableRemoteMethod("upsert", true);
  Task.disableRemoteMethod("updateAll", true);
  Task.disableRemoteMethod("updateAttributes", false);
  Task.disableRemoteMethod('createChangeStream', true);

  Task.disableRemoteMethod("find", true);
  Task.disableRemoteMethod("replaceOrCreate", true);

};
```

For example, for Project, User etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mixin and disable these remote methods there

Comment: That's it! Thank you.